# Create a repetitive image pattern using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

As the title says, I am trying to create a tile pattern by repeating the same image throughout my canvas element.

This is what I've tried so far: `<canvas id='c' width='345' height='345'></canvas>`

```
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c',{backgroundColor: "#fff"});
const logo = 'https://www.logomaker.com/wpstatic/uploads/2018/11/bakerylogo2.png';
canvas.add(
        new fabric.Line([7,10,17,10],{
            fill: "grey",
            stroke: "grey",
            strokeWidth: 3           
        }),
        new fabric.Line([10,10,10,150],{
            fill: "grey",
            stroke: "grey",
            strokeWidth: 3
        }),
        new fabric.IText("500mm",{
            left: 20,
            top: 152,
            fill: "grey",
            stroke: "grey",
            fontSize: 10,
            angle: 90
        }),
        new fabric.Line([10, 190, 10, 315], {
            fill: "grey",
            stroke: "grey",
            strokeWidth: 3
        }),
        new fabric.Line([7,315,17,315],{
            fill: "grey",
            stroke: "grey",
            strokeWidth: 3           
        }),
        new fabric.Line([30,333,30,320],{
            fill: "grey",
            stroke: "grey",
            strokeWidth: 3           
        }),
        new fabric.Line([30,325,150,325],{
            fill: "grey",
            stroke: "grey",
            strokeWidth: 3           
        }),
        new fabric.IText("380mm",{
            left: 152,
            top: 320,
            fill: "grey",
            stroke: "grey",
            fontSize: 10,
        }),
        new fabric.Line([187,325,310,325],{
            fill: "grey",
            stroke: "grey",
            strokeWidth: 3           
        }),
        new fabric.Line([310,333,310,320],{
            fill: "grey",
            stroke: "grey",
            strokeWidth: 3           
        }),
    )
    fabric.Image.fromURL(logo, function(img) {
        var oImg = img.set({
            left: 40,
            top: 40,
            angle: 310
        }).scale(0.1);
        canvas.add(oImg);
    })
    canvas.renderTop();
```

, but now I am stuck.

Here's a jsfiddle if it helps to visualize the problem faster: https://jsfiddle.net/1fevg8dc/3/

Any help in the right direction would help me greatly, as I really struggle with fabricjs's documentation.

My end goal would be to apply a greyscale filter on the image(declared as logo) and rotate the image at 45 degrees and create the pattern inside the lines that I've

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tiled, repeated pattern as a fabric.js background is not that hard to do actually. However, the problem in your case is that you want it to be at an angle and a grayscale filter applied.

Anyway, first we need to create a canvas.js `Shape` object - which will serve as our background and hence needs to cover the whole viewport.

```
let shape = new fabric.Rect({
    width: canvas.width,
    height: canvas.height,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    selectable: false
});
```

We don't add it to the stage yet though. As we want to fill the Shape with an image, we need to load it first. For this task we utilize the `.fromURL()` method of the Image object.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL("https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.logomaker.com/wpstatic/uploads/2018/11/bakerylogo2.png", function(img) {}, {crossOrigin: 'anonymous'})
```

Inside the empty callback function - `function(img) {}` - the following must happen:

- Convert the image to grayscale
- Use this image as a fill for the shape
- Rotate the fill e.g. 45°

The first step is done using fabric.js built-in filters

```
img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());
img.applyFilters();
```

Step number two involves creating a `Pattern` object which is then applied to the `Shape` object.

The last step is the tricky part. A fill doesn't have a rotation property. Instead it's transformed by a transformation matrix using it's `patternTransform` property. This patternTransform is an array of 6 values which control the position, scale and skew. For a 45 degree rotation it has to be like this:

```
let angle = -45 * Math.PI / 180;
let transformMatrix=[Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle), -Math.sin(angle), Math.cos(angle), 0, 0];
```

Let's elaborate a bit on the transformation matrix. As I said, it contains six values. If we give
those a meaningful name it looks a bit like this:

```
matrix= [scaleX, skewY, skewX, scaleY, translateX, translateY];
```

We can see that there is no value which controls the rotation. That's because in a matrix, a rotation
is a combination of skew and scale. If we look back at our own transformation:

```
let transformMatrix = [Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle), -Math.sin(angle), Math.cos(angle), 0, 0];
```

it's indeed the `scaleX`, `skewY`, `skewX` and `scaleY` properties being populated.

If we were to alter the scale of a matrix, everything we would need to change it's `scaleX` and `scaleY`
properties. In this case however it's a bit different as we already applied a rotation. Fortunately
it ain't that hard. The scale itself is a decimal number, where **1** means no change, **2** is the double scale
and **0.5** is half the scale for example. So if we want to make the pattern half it's original size, we
need to multiply scaleX, skewY, skewX and scaleY by 0.5.

```
let angle = -45 * Math.PI / 180;
let scale = 0.5;
let transformMatrix = [Math.cos(angle) * scale, Math.sin(angle) * scale, -Math.sin(angle) * scale, Math.cos(angle) * scale, 0, 0];
```

Now if we put everything together we will come up with this:

```js
let canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

let shape = new fabric.Rect({
  width: canvas.width,
  height: canvas.height,
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  selectable: false
});

fabric.Image.fromURL("https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.logomaker.com/wpstatic/uploads/2018/11/bakerylogo2.png", function(img) {
  img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());
  img.applyFilters();

  let angle = -45 * Math.PI / 180;
  let scale = 0.5;
  shape.set('fill', new fabric.Pattern({
    source: img._element,
    repeat: 'repeat',
    patternTransform: [Math.cos(angle) * scale, Math.sin(angle) * scale, -Math.sin(angle) * scale, Math.cos(angle) * scale, 0, 0]
  }));

  canvas.add(shape);
  canvas.renderAll();

}, {
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/500/fabric.min.js" integrity="sha512-ft2xOUYF7h2UeYQUbol4GJHrkGPVrgimINEYwLI23hyxN1JIy6EEj2vEc8RWWIIExvUKZvYq3oJTDrbif2oSVw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Comment: 1 last question: how would i scale down the image in the pattern?

Comment: i've tried adding img.scaleToHeight and img.scaleToWidth inside fabric.Image.fromURL, but it doesn't seem like it is doing anything

Comment: I've updated my answer to include scale @tearswep.